# Converting to btrfs from md raid5 with lvm

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, lvm, btrfs, mdadm

I have decided to start the transition to btrfs this weekend. I have a desktop with one md raid1 which is used for boot, and one large md raid5 for everything else. On top of the md raid5, I have LVM with vg-root, vg-swap and vg-home.

My idea is that I keep the raid1 with ext4 as boot and I won't convert the LVM at once. Instead, I'll create a new btrfs root on the raid5, create a fresh home directory, move over configs and bare necessities, and then move things over as I need them. That way, the size of the potential restore will increase as the likelihood of bugs decrease. Now the question is; how do I actually do that? :)

I'm hoping for some expert advise here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, you don't need a separate /boot partition on a raid1; grub2 can boot directly from lvm on raid5.

If your raid5 is partitioned and currently LVM is using /dev/md1p1 as the PV, then you can shrink the PV, shrink the partition, and create a new partition using the free space to use for btrfs.

You will need to use `parted` to shrink the lvm partition after using `pvresize` to have LVM release part of it.  You will need to have `parted` use sectors for the units and delete the LVM partition, and recreate it with the same start sector, but a shorter length.  This will require either that the partition not be in use ( do it from a livecd ), or will complain that it could not update the kernel, and you will have to reboot for it to take affect.

After that, you can use `gparted` to create a new btrfs partition using the free space, then add it to /etc/fstab, mount it, and transfer some files.  To move more space, you will need to repeat the `pvresize` and `parted` shrink step, then use `gparted` to move the btrfs partition to the left, and expand.  This will take a long time because it has to copy all of the existing data in the btrfs partition.

It would be much easier, safer, and faster to simply create a new LV using whatever space is currently free in the VG, and format it with btrfs, then transfer some files, shrink an existing LV with `resize2fs` ( assuming it's ext4, and it will need to be unmounted to do this ) and `lvresize`, then add the space to the btrfs lv with `lvresize`, and tell btrfs to use the new space with `btrfs filesystem resize max /path/to/btrfs-mount`.